# Bulk insert (of 1000 documents) to mongodb server is 1 IOPS in GCP, or it's 1000 iops?

Tags: mongodb, performance, google-cloud-platform, bulk

I read GCP [docs](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/disks/performance) about performance, and I [read](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/bulk-write-operations/) about mongo bulk operations, and I'm wondering if bulk operation count as 1 operation (so I can do 30 like that per second per GB for example) or it's equal to the number of operations in the bulk.
thank you!

Comment: The answer is neither. A database write operation will generate multiple I/Os. Unless you examine the exact layout of the data block records, the type of I/O that the database journal creates, the type of update request, you won't know. One bulk operation could generate a few I/Os or hundreds of I/Os.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

MongoDB *bulk* operations reduce network and processing overhead but have little effect on disk IOPS.

Disk IOPS are always proportional to the *number of documents* inserted/updated/deleted, also in bulk mode.

But it's not 1-to-1; in addition to # of documents, disk IOPS are dependent on the indices, journal, checkpoints, shards and cache size.

A very rough estimate would be `(2 + #_of_indexes) * #_of_documents_updated / seconds`.

[image: MongoDB IOPS Calculation]

Source: [Sizing MongoDB Clusters](https://www.slideshare.net/mongodb/sizing-mongodb-clusters)

Comment: See also [this IOPS sizing spreadsheet](https://github.com/jayrunkel/mdbw2017Sizing).